# Injecting HTML on (arbitrary) admin pages

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to create a plugin that is able to inject some html on admin-pages, no matter if these are post, pages, settings or any option page for a plugin.

So I am searching for a suitable hook, so that I could run code like this (pseudo-code):

```
function plugin_inject_html()
{
    if( preg_match( '<regexp to parse the url>', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) > 0 )
    {
        echo 'my html here';
    }
}
add_action( '<the hook I am searching for', 'plugin_inject_html' );
```

So my question is:

Which action or filter would be suitable to hook in, so that the result of the echo would arrive in the right location of the overall admin-page (inside the `div.wpbody-content`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the source of the `/wp-admin/admin-header.php` page you find the following actions:

Inside `div#wpbody`:

- `in_admin_header`,

Inside `div.wpbody-content`:

- `network_admin_notices`
- `user_admin_notices`
- `admin_notices`
- `all_admin_notices`

I'm not sure what you mean by the *right* location, but I guess the `all_admin_notices` action would be the most suitable one for you?

Comment: thank you, that seems pretty much to be what I am looking for! Thanks!!!